# Disable drag and drop between two different ReorderLists from AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, reorderlist

I have several ReorderLists on a page.

Each list has items added to it via a postback, which updates the list.
PostBackOnReorder is true, and we have an event handler hooked up on OnItemReorder.

The problem is that the drag and drop seems to allow for an item to be dragged from one list to another (which is something we do not want), and when it is dropped, the item disappears until another one is added to the list.

Is there any way to disable dropping an item into another list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could tell from some debugging, this is a problem with the control itself.
I've patched the source to use ClientID instead of ID to differenciate between two different lists and created a bug report [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/WorkItem)